# Monoid table using presentations

Tags: tables

A monoid table is just a table that shows the result of a binary operation. It's like a multiplication table but it may not commute x*y != y*x and may not have unique entries.

The idea is simple though

```
   x    y
x x*x  x*y
y y*x  y*y
```

For more than two elements we get more than two entries. Usually there is an identity(a 1 like element that "does nothing).

I have a desire to create some tables using latex and wondering if there is a relatively easy way to create these?

Ok, surely one can do it by hand but I might need to create a lot so it should be automated.

Further more, I actually have rules that I might need to generate or simplify the table.

e.g., x*x = y or x*y = x*y

These rules essentially "short circuit" the table so it is not just arbitrary multiplications(essentially what is known as freeness(free from constraints)).

Of course I have many elements, say 8 and may have some rules for some and not others. I may also need to modify some cells after the generation of the table. Also, in this case * can be written as concatenation so x*y = xy.

Does anyone have a simple way to basically give the elements used,e.g., S = {x,y}, generate the "multiplication" table and possibly also specify a presentation P = {xx = y, xy = yx} and then be able to modify the table after it is generated that is conducive to creating and reusing many of these types of constructions?

I don't really care too much how it looks. A simple table or matrix format would do... should be easily used along side of others though and centering and all that. Mainly just want to generate them easily and deal with the presentation issue. The presentation issue just isn't a replacement as one might need to carry out several iteration sof the operations to determine the simplest form. The table should try to be closed in this sense(only using elements from the set and it should be the simplest representation. E.g., if xy = yx and xx = y then xyx = yxx = yy. If yy doesn't exist in the table then it can't be reduced but if it equals some other element then it can).

Comment: How this is related to LaTeX. How to write an matrix? If it is, please show as what you try so far.

Comment: I would suggest to do this in your favourite programming language, to generate the LaTeX code.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I thought about. Just thought there might be a native latex3e version that uses loops and such.

Comment: LaTeX should be Turing-complete, son theoretically it must be possible. But even with LaTeX3, it is often tedious and error-prone. Like hammering nails with a screwdriver, but worse.